# Template is displaying object name instead of value

Tags: django

My template used to show the data correctly before I changed my model to add the following OrgLevel prior to my custom User table.

```
class OrgLevel(models.Model):

    coid = models.CharField(db_column='Coid',  max_length=5, primary_key = True, unique = True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    slevel = models.CharField(db_column='SLevel', max_length=6)  # Field name made lowercase.
    blevel = models.CharField(db_column='BLevel', max_length=6)  # Field name made lowercase.
    rlevel = models.CharField(db_column='RLevel', max_length=6)  # Field name made lowercase.
    dlevel = models.CharField(db_column='DLevel', max_length=6)  # Field name made lowercase.

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'OrgLevel'
```

My Custom User model is defined as the following:

```
class User(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):

    email = models.EmailField(unique=True)
    username = models.CharField(max_length=7, unique=True)
    formattedusername = models.CharField(max_length=11, unique=True, primary_key = True)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=40)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=140)
    date_joined = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    is_staff = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_cfo = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    facility = models.CharField(max_length=140)
    officename = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    jobdescription = models.CharField(max_length=140)
    positioncode = models.CharField(max_length = 100)
    positiondescription = models.CharField(max_length=140)
    coid = models.OneToOneField(OrgLevel, null=True, blank = True)
    streetaddress = models.CharField(max_length=140)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'username'

    class Meta:
        app_label = 'accounts'
        db_table = "user"

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.formattedusername = '{domain}\{username}'.format(
            domain='HCA', username=self.username)
        super(User, self).save(*args, **kwargs);

    def get_short_name(self):
        return self.username
```

In my view I have the owner defined as:

```
def profile(request):
    owner = User.objects.get (formattedusername=request.user.formattedusername)
    reportdetail = QVReportAccess.objects.filter(ntname = owner.formattedusername, active = 1).values('report_name_sc')

    reportIds = QVReportAccess.objects.filter(ntname = owner.formattedusername).values_list('report_id', flat=True)
    reportaccess = QvReportList.objects.filter(report_id__in= reportIds).values_list('report_name_sc', flat = True).distinct()
    reportGroups = QVReportAccess.objects.filter(ntname = owner.formattedusername).values_list('report_group_id', flat=True)
    reportlist = QvReportList.objects.filter(~Q(report_id__in= reportIds)).exclude(active=0)

    allreports = 'placeholder'

    if allreports in reportaccess:
        bhreportgrouplist = None
        cereportgrouplist = None
        finreportgrouplist = None
        careportgrouplist = None
        pireportgrouplist = None
        screportgrouplist = None
        dssreportgrouplist = None
        psgreportgrouplist = None
        othreportgrouplist = None
        showbutton = None
    else:
        bhreportgrouplist = QvReportList.objects.filter(~Q(report_id__in= reportIds)).filter(report_group_id = 200)
        cereportgrouplist = QvReportList.objects.filter(~Q(report_id__in= reportIds)).filter(report_group_id = 500)
        finreportgrouplist = QvReportList.objects.filter(~Q(report_id__in= reportIds)).filter(report_group_id = 600)
        careportgrouplist = QvReportList.objects.filter(~Q(report_id__in= reportIds)).filter(report_group_id = 800)
        pireportgrouplist = QvReportList.objects.filter(~Q(report_id__in= reportIds)).filter(report_group_id = 1100)
        screportgrouplist = QvReportList.objects.filter(~Q(report_id__in= reportIds)).filter(report_group_id = 1200)
        dssreportgrouplist = QvReportList.objects.filter(~Q(report_id__in= reportIds)).filter(report_group_id = 1300)
        psgreportgrouplist = QvReportList.objects.filter(~Q(report_id__in= reportIds)).filter(report_group_id = 1400)
        othreportgrouplist = QvReportList.objects.filter(~Q(report_id__in= reportIds)).filter(report_group_id = 99999)
        showbutton = ""

        print (f"owner:{owner.coid}")
        print (f"reportdetail:{reportdetail}")
        print (f"reportids:{reportIds}")
        print (f"reportaccess:{reportaccess}")
        print (f"reportgroups:{reportGroups}")
        print (f"reportlist:{reportlist}")



    args = {'user':owner, 'applicationaccess':reportaccess, 'applicationlist':reportlist, 'bhgrouplist':bhreportgrouplist, 'cegrouplist':cereportgrouplist, 'fingrouplist':finreportgrouplist
          , 'cagrouplist':careportgrouplist, 'pigrouplist':pireportgrouplist, 'scgrouplist':screportgrouplist, 'dssgrouplist':dssreportgrouplist, 'psggrouplist':psgreportgrouplist
          , 'othgrouplist':othreportgrouplist, 'showbutton':showbutton}

    return render(request, 'accounts/profile.html', args)
```

If I print owner with:

```
print (f"owner:{owner.formattedusername}")
```

It will print the owner correctly.  However, if I print owner.coid it will print the output as:

```
owner:OrgLevel object
```

How can I get the owner.coid to print as the value instead of the object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`owner.coid.coid`

The first `coid` refers to the OrgLevel object. The second `coid` refers to the `coid` field within that object.

I strongly suggest using different names for the fields. Instead of `coid` as a field in User I suggest using `org` or `orglevel`. As far as the second `coid`, I recommend sticking to the default automatic `id` primary key provided by Django, except if you need to maintain compatibility with a pre-Django database.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, i figured it was something simple like that.  By adding the foreign key I essentially created an additional level on my User table.  Unfortunately i'll be unable to rename the tables as they are pre-existing production database tables.